# Calculate stochastic integral $\int_0^T s^2 W_s dW_s$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I faced some troubles trying to evaluate Ito's integral $\int_0^T s^2 W_s dW_s$ by definition. My attempt is $\int_0^T s^2 W_s dW_s = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} t_i^2 W_{t_i} (W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}) = X - \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} t_i^2 W_{t_i}^2 = X - (T^3+2T^2\int_0^TW_sdW_s)$, since $W_T^2 = T + 2\int_0^T W_s dW_s$. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to proceed with the first summand $X$ by definition, to be more precise, I stuck with $W_{t_{i+1}}W_{t_i}$ term.

Can anyone show me how to deal with it? If there is any mistake in my evaluation of the second term, please notify me too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluat(ing) a stochastic integral"?

Comment: @Did, I mean to calculate it (find value) using the definition of Ito integral.

Comment: Precisely. The result is a random variable hence you cannot "calculate" it. Sorry but have you the slightest idea of the definitions of the notions involved here?

Comment: Do you know the correlation function for the Brownian motion? It will help you to understand the behavior of a large sum of terms of the form $W_{t_{i+1}} W_{t_i}$.

Comment: @lan, yes, since $\mbox{corr}(W_s,W_t) = \sqrt\frac{\min(s,t)}{\max(s,t)}$ we are going to conclude that $\mbox{corr}(W_{t_{i+1},W_{t_i}}) = 1$ for large $t$, so $W_{t_{i+1}}W_{t_i}$ behaves similarly to $W_{t_i}^2$? I found it rather strange.

Comment: @Did, I understand that the result of integration with respect to stochastic process is another stochastic process or, from another point of view, a function of time and Wiener process (Brownian motion). The problem is in my English -- I'm not sure what is the proper word to name it (maybe "find integral"?) and it seems that you misunderstood me.

Comment: $W_{t_{i+1}} W_{t_i}$ indeed behaves on average like $W_{t_i}^2$, precisely because on average $W_{t_i}(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})$ is zero, which is related to the martingale property. (Note that I actually meant to refer to the *covariance* function, but the correlation function does the same job for slightly more work.) The whole idea of a direct calculation of an Ito integral from the definition is essentially to say that the Ito integral *is* such an average, and thus to justify replacing the things being summed by appropriate averages.

Comment: @Did: I think what OP is seeking is some analytic function $f:\mathbf R^2\to\mathbf R\ \ni f(T,W_T) = \int_0^T\cdots$. It would be an interesting question asking under what kind of Ito integrals would acquire such a form. There is a theory on analytic indefinite integration of real functions. I wonder if there is an analog for Ito integrals.

Comment: @Hans Of course this is what they are after. Note that 1. it would have been much preferable that the OP comes to this realization by themselves, and 2. that such a function cannot exist in the present case, which can be proved as in the answer below, or by showing that the integral is not $\sigma(W_T)$-measurable.

Comment: @Did: I should have realized the answer to my question in my last comment via Ito's lemma. Would you please show the integral is not $\sigma(W_T)$-measurable? 

On another note, would you like to take a look at my question math.stackexchange.com/q/2454836/64809?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is a random variable, but it looks like you're looking for an equality similar to something like $$\frac{1}{2}(W_T^2 - T) = \int_0^T W_s \,dW_s.$$

In other words, you're looking for a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ so that $$f(W_T,T) = \int_0^T s^2 W_s\,dW_s.$$
This interpretation of your question is mentioned in the comments, and I think that this is the sort of thing you're looking for.  By Itô's Lemma, we would need $f$ to satisfy $$\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = t^2 x, \\
\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = 0, \\
f(0,0)=0 \end{cases}$$
which you can check has no solution since the first equation implies $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ is constant with respect to $x$, thereby making the second equation impossible.

To answer the question about "indefinite integration for Itô integrals," the answer is that you can "find an antiderivative" (i.e. an answer of the form $f(W_T,T)$) when you're integrating $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ where $f$ satisfies the diffusion equation $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}.$$
This can be seen from Itô's Lemma.

Comment: Oh, darn. I should have given it a bit more thought after I have made my comment you are referring to and before I turned to my own work. :-P Good work! +1

Answer (score 0):

As an example for solving $\int_{0}^{T}s^2 W_{s}\mathrm{d}W_{s}$ let define double differentiable function $F(t,W_{t})$ of two real variables $t$ and $W_{t}$. With this function combined with Ito's Lemma follows:
\begin{equation*}
     \begin{array}{rcl}
      \mathrm{d}F&=& \displaystyle \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t+\frac{\partial F}{\partial W_{t}}\mathrm{d}W_{t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial W_{t}^{2}}\mathrm{d}W_{t}^2+\cdots \\
     \end{array}
    \end{equation*}

Now set $\displaystyle \frac{\partial F}{\partial W_{t}}=t^2 W_{t}$ then follows for $F=\displaystyle\tfrac{1}{2}t^2 W_{t}^2$, $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}=\displaystyle t W_{t}^2$ and $\dfrac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial W_{t}^{2}}=\displaystyle t^2$:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle\mathrm{d}F&\approx& \displaystyle \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t+\frac{\partial F}{\partial W_{t}}\mathrm{d}W_{t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^{2}F}{\partial W_{t}^{2}}\mathrm{d}t \\
    \displaystyle\mathrm{d}\left(\tfrac{1}{2}t^2 W_{t}^2\right)&\approx&\displaystyle t W_{t}^2\mathrm{d}t+t^2 W_{t}\mathrm{d}W_{t}+\tfrac{1}{2}t^2\mathrm{d}t \\
    \displaystyle\int_{0}^{T}\mathrm{d}\left(\tfrac{1}{2}s^2 W_{s}^2\right)&\approx&\displaystyle\int_{0}^{T}s W_{s}^2\mathrm{d}s+\int_{0}^{T}s^2 W_{s}\mathrm{d}W_{s}+\tfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{T}s^2\mathrm{d}s \\
\displaystyle\tfrac{1}{2}T^2 W_{T}^2&\approx&\displaystyle \int_{0}^{T}s W_{s}^2\mathrm{d}s+\int_{0}^{T}s^2 W_{s}\mathrm{d}W_{s}+\tfrac{1}{6}T^3\Rightarrow \\ 
\displaystyle\int_{0}^{T}s^2 W_{s}\mathrm{d}W_{s}&\approx&\displaystyle\tfrac{1}{2}T^2 W_{T}^2-\int_{0}^{T}s W_{s}^2\mathrm{d}s-\tfrac{1}{6}T^3 \\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

Let calculate the expected value for $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{T}s W_{s}^2\mathrm{d}s$:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle\mathbb{E}\left [\int_{0}^{T}s W_{s}^2\mathrm{d}s\right]&=&\displaystyle\int_{0}^{T}\mathbb{E}\left [s W_{s}^2\right ]\mathrm{d}s \\
&=&\displaystyle\int_{0}^{T}s^{2}\mathrm{d}s \\
&=&\displaystyle\tfrac{1}{3}T^3 \\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

Let define $W_{s}$ as a continuous time stochastic process with independent and identically normal distributed random variables than follows for $\mathbb{E}\left [s W_{s}^2\right]$.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle\mathbb{E}\left [s W_{s}^2\right ]&=&\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} s x^2 f\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x \\
&=&\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}s x^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}\,e^{-\dfrac{x^2}{2s}}\mathrm{d}x \\
&=&s^{2} \\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
Finally with $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{T}s W_{s}^2\mathrm{d}s=\tfrac{1}{3}T^3$ follows the desired answer:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle\int_{0}^{T}s^2 W_{s}\mathrm{d}W_{s}&\approx&\displaystyle\tfrac{1}{2}T^2 W_{T}^2-\tfrac{1}{3}T^3-\tfrac{1}{6}T^3 \\
&\approx&\displaystyle\tfrac{1}{2}T^2 W_{T}^2-\tfrac{1}{2}T^3\\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

Comment: I am sorry but this answer contradicts the accepted one that says that the integral cannot be expressed in that form... further, in the last integral you show that it has expected value equal to $T^3/3$ but this does not mean that it is equal a.s. to $T^3/3$ as your substitutions seem to suggest...

Comment: Further, what is that tilde instead of the equal sign?