# Direct way to check if a random variable is $W_T$ measurable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, variance

Inspired by this:

[Calculate stochastic integral $\int_0^T s^2 W_s dW_s$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456341/calculate-stochastic-integral-int-0t-s2-w-s-dw-s/4357383#comment9098394_4357383) ,

I was asking myself this question:

Given a stochastic integral:

$I=\int_0^T f(W_s) ds$

is there a direct way to check if it is $W_{T}$-measurable ?

I tried to do a calculation for $f(W_s)=W_s$ and I wanted to ask:

1. if my calculations/reasonings make sense and are conceptually correct ( even if the might be an overkill )
2. if there are other ways that do not use the Ito formula to prove the same (maybe that can be applied to a generic $f$?).

I thought this ( a bit intuitively ):

Prop: $I$ is $W_T$ measurable iff $Var(I|W_T)=0$.

The idea is that if $I$ is already $W_T$ measurable, it is a function of $W_T$ and therefore its variance given $W_T$ should vanish.

If the proposition is true, than we can evaluate:

$Var(I|W_T)=\int_0^T \int_0^T cov(W_sW_{s'}|W_T) dsds'=2 \int_0^{T}d{s'}\int_0^{s'}ds \ cov(W_sW_{s'}|W_T)$

, where now in the covariance we have $s<s'<T$, just for convenience.

Now using that for a Brownian motion $E[W_uW_t]=min(u,t)$, that the joint of $W_s,W_s',W_T$ is Gaussian, we can evaluate the conditional covariance (I may add a bit more details on the calculation):

$cov(W_sW_{s'}|W_T)=s-\frac{ss'}{T}$

and finally:

$Var(I|W_T)=\frac{T^3}{24}>0$

Note that $Var(I|W_T)$ could have been a function of $W_T$ but, according to my calculations, it is not. Anyway this is positive and therefore we can conclude (?) that $I$ is not $W_T$-measurable ?

Comment: In the answer I just deleted I handled the case $\int_0^Tf(W_s)\,dW_s$ but obviously you are asking about $\int_0^Tf(W_s)\,ds\,$ Thanks '@JoseAvilez' for pointing that out. I believer that $\int_0^Tf(W_s)\,ds\,$ is in general not $W_T$-measurable (unless $f$ is constant). The trouble I have with your proof though is that your variance does not depend on $f\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. I think you're correct. The argument you posted can be amended. For instance, if $f(W_s) = W_s$, then integrating by parts gives $\int_0^T W_s ds = TW_T - \int_0^T sdW_s$. Your argument can then be applied to the second term in this expression. This generalises to $f \in C^1$.

Comment: @JoseAvilez . I don't think $\int_0^Ts\,dW_s$ is $W_T$-measurable. More than happy to be wrong again ;) .

Comment: @KurtG. I agree with that: I don't think it's $W_T$-measurable either, but it certainly is $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable. Apologies if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @Kurt G. My answer is limited to f(w)=w. I was not aiming for generality, as I wrote I would like first to know if my reasoning in that particular case are correct and second if there are other proofs that do not use Ito formula

Comment: @Kurt G. Please do not delete answers when there are conversations going on (even some comments of mine) and continue the conversation in the main thread, having lost reference to the answer. Note that you can 'undelete' an answer, that would be nice...

Comment: @Thomas . Undeleted and adapted to the case of the $ds$-integral.

Comment: @Kurt G. Thanks for the undeletion :)

Answer (score 2):

Under an additional smoothness assumption I show that the integral $I=\int_0^Tf(W_s)\,ds$ is not $W_T$-measurable unless $f$ is constant:

**Lemma.**  *Assume
$$\tag{1}
\int_0^Tf(W_t,t)\,dt=g(W_T,T)
$$
holds for all $T$ where $g(x,t)$ is twice differentiable in $x$ and differentiable in $t$. Then, both $f$ and $g$ don't depend on $x\,.$ In particular, only the integral with deterministic integrand is trivially $W_T$-measurable.*

Recall that $W_T$ measurability of the integral is, by the  Dynkin-Doob lemma, equivalent to the existence of a *Borel measurable* $g(x,t)$ that satisfies (1). The assumption of smoothness helps to simplify the matters.

Proof. Assume (1). Then by Ito's formula
\begin{align}
f(W_t,t)\,dt=g_x(W_t,t)\,dW_t+\frac{1}{2}g_{xx}(W_t,t)\,dt+g_t(W_t,t)\,dt\,.
\end{align}
This implies
\begin{align}
0&=g_x(x,t)\,,\quad 0=g_{xx}(x,t)\,,\tag{2}\\
f(x,t)&=g_t(x,t)\,.\tag{3}
\end{align}
The first of equations (2) means that $g$ cannot depend on $x\,.$ Therefore, if (1) holds,
$f$ cannot depend on $x$ (by (3)) and both sides of (1) must be deterministic.

Comment: Thank you. The argument I think needs to be refined. Also int_0^T w dw seems to be path dependent, but it is W_T measurable. I know it is a different type of integral, but the point is exactly to show rigorously that this phenomenon is not happening

Comment: By the way, do you see conceptual errors in my procedure ( I am interested in knowing if the calculations I did are technically correct, even if they might be an overkill ) ?

Comment: The OP is asking about $\int_0^T f(W_s) ds$, not $\int_0^T f(W_s)dW_s$

Comment: Just realized that. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks (+1). This is a great answer related to the question. I cannot accept the answer though because you did not review my method and you made use of the Ito lemma (I was searching for a more direct / elementary approach as I wrote in the original post ). But thanks again for the contribution!